# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find : No such file or directory

Tags: c++, makefile, sdl

I'm following [this](http://twinklebear.github.io/sdl2%20tutorials/2013/08/18/lesson-3-sdl-extension-libraries/) SDL tutorial to try and make use of some SDL extension libraries. My code is identical to [theirs](https://raw.github.com/Twinklebear/TwinklebearDev-Lessons/master/Lesson3/src/main.cpp) but I am still unable to `make` the file which leads me to believe the problem is in my `makefile` which looks like this:

```
CXX = g++
# Update these paths to match your installation
# You may also need to update the linker option rpath, which sets where to look for
# the SDL2 libraries at runtime to match your install
SDL_LIB = -L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2 -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib, -lSDL2_image
SDL_INCLUDE = -I/usr/local/include
# You may need to change -std=c++11 to -std=c++0x if your compiler is a bit older
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -c -std=c++11 $(SDL_INCLUDE)
LDFLAGS = $(SDL_LIB)
EXE = SDL_Lesson3

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): main.o
    $(CXX) $< $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm *.o && rm $(EXE)
```

That `makefile` worked fine for previous examples. The only thing that has changed in this example is line 5 where I added `-lSDL2_image` as per the tutorial. When I try `make` the file I get the following traceback:

```
rony@comet:~/Documents/cpp/helloworld/lesson3$ make
g++ main.o -L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2 -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib, -lSDL2_image -o SDL_Lesson3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find : No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [SDL_Lesson3] Error 1
```

Is there an error with my makefile? Have I not installed the library correctly?

Comment: You have a spurious comma in the end of -Wl option.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is this rogue comma:

```
SDL_LIB = -L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2 -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib, -lSDL2_image
                                                           ^
```

causing the linker to look for libraries in a non-existent directory with an empty name, as well as `/usr/local/lib`. Removing the comma should fix it.